# Editing string variables

Tags: android, json, api

i have a string variable for a JSON API im trying to read
in it i have to add latitude and longitude
i got the latitude and longitude inside a variable and the site inside a variable
how can i now edit the string to add my variables in?

```
// JSON URL
private static String url = "https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?lat=42.93167&long=-81.22807";


        // latitude variable
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // longitude variable
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

i would like to edit the

```
lat=42.93167&long=-81.22807
```

(the numbers after lat= and long=

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
// latitude variable
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

// longitude variable
double longitude = location.getLongitude();

// JSON URL
private static String url = "https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?lat="+Double.toString(latitude)+"&long="+Double.toString(longitude);
```

Comment: thank you, i will try a mixture of urs and Gabe's answer

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the base url private static `String url = "https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?"`;  and when you know the 2 variables form the complete url via concatenation?

Comment: ya it is like that, sorry i did not state properly